# 'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command on Windows when installed globally

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc

I've seen bunch of `'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command` issues here on StackOverflow but none of them could help me solve my problem.

I've installed typescript globally with:

```
npm install -g typescript
```

There are `tsc` and `tsc.cmd` files in `C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\npm` directory. So `%AppData%\npm\tsc --version` command works.

I've got `C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\npm` directory in my user's PATH.

More, when I run `where tsc` command in arbitrary directory, I get:

```
C:\Users\<user_name>\Desktop>where tsc
C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc
C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.cmd
```

However, when I simply try to run `tsc`, I got:

```
C:\Users\<user_name>\Desktop>tsc
'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Exactly the same problem occurs with `grunt` and `uglifyjs`.

Comment: try this npx tsc ttest.ts

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this problem.

`C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\npm` indeed was in user's `PATH` variable. I also have system variable called `Path` (yes, just first letter is uppercased) and there was no `C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\npm` in there.

When I added it to system's `Path`, it finally started to work.

Not sure that this is ok that two of my path variables have different names (in terms of cases). Also not sure that this situation led to problems.
Would be glad if someone could clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the linux console for windows the cygwin console., And run the command tsc from that console, I know it does not change much but sometimes I have solved many problems with that console.

https://www.cygwin.com/

Comment: Don't need it, you can run it in `cmd`, `powershell`, etc